# Displaying label on first form of Django formset only

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

This is a super straightforward question but I can't seem to find any concise answer it. I have a Django formset that displays different tags associated with an object. Here is the form:

```
class TagForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tags = kwargs.pop('tags')
        super(TagForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['tags'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(tag, tag) for tag in tags], label="Tags")
```

I'm rendering the formset using the following code:

```
<li class="list-group-item">
    <ul class="list-inline" id="tag-group">
        {{ tag_formset.management_form }}
        {% for tag_form in tag_formset %}
            <li class="list-inline-item">
                {{ tag_form.tags.label_tag }}
                {{ tag_form.tags }}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</li>
```

My problem is that this creates a label for each tag. Since this is an inline list, I'd only like to display the label prior to the first tag (and no others). I can't find any straightforward way to do this (without modifying the for loop with explicit logic checking if it is the first form being rendered). I optimistically tried to modify my rendering code to the following:

```
<li class="list-group-item">
    <ul class="list-inline" id="tag-group">
        {{ tag_formset.management_form }}
        {{ tag_form.empty_form.label_tag }}
        {% for tag_form in tag_formset %}
            <li class="list-inline-item">
                {{ tag_form.tags }}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</li>
```

but this didn't display any labels at all. Is there an idiomatic way to only display the form label prior to the first form in a formset?

Answer (score 0):

The code below is working for me. The main idea is simple. Make a Table and in the headers put the tags. and in the table body put only the data. Try it and let me know.

{% for f1 in formset %}
{{ f1.management_form|crispy }}

```
    {% crispy f1 %}
    {% endcomment %}

    <table{% if form_id %} id="{{ form_id }}_table" {% endif%} class="table table-striped table-condensed">
        <thead>
            {% if formset.readonly and not formset.queryset.exists %}
            {% else %}
            <tr>
                <td>

                </td>

                {% for field in formset.forms.0 %}
                {% if field.label and not field.is_hidden %}
                <th for="{{ field.auto_id }}"
                    class="control-label {% if field.field.required  %}requiredField{% endif %}">
                    {{ field.label|safe }}{% if field.field.required  %}<span
                        class="asteriskField">*</span>{% endif %}
                </th>
                {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            {% endif %}
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            {% comment %} <tr class="hidden empty-form">
                {% for field in formset.empty_form %}
                {% include 'bootstrap/field.html' with tag="td" form_show_labels=False %}
                {% endfor %}
            </tr> {% endcomment %}

            {% for form2 in formset2 %}
            {% if form2_show_errors and not form2.is_extra %}
            {% include "bootstrap/errors.html" %}
            {% endif %}

            <tr>
                <td>


                    <a class="btn btn-info pull-right" {% comment %}
                        href="{% url 'set_final' formfs.pk %}/?next={% url 'update-well-view' form.pk %}">
                        {% endcomment %}
                        href="{% url 'Scouts-home'  %}"> Set Final
                    </a>


                </td>
                {% for field in form2 %}
                {% include 'bootstrap/field.html' with tag="td" form2_show_labels=False %}
                {% endfor %}


            </tr>
            {% endfor %}


        </tbody>
        </table>
```